# Web Speech API supports input text, select, check box and Input text type numeric has also?

Tags: javascript, web, speech-recognition

In the form below I am trying to insert the option to fill by voice.

In the examples of the Web Speech API plugin I realize that only the Text Area field has the function, I would like to know.

If the Web Speech API supports input text, select, check box

Input text type has also numerical?

**In the example of the form below how to have this support**

```html
 <form class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
    
    <!-- Form Name -->
    <legend>Form Name</legend>
    
    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="name">Name</label>  
      <div class="col-md-4">
      <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Type your name" class="form-control input-md">
      <span class="help-block">Required field</span>  
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Select Basic -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="city">City</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <select id="city" name="city" class="form-control">
          <option value="1">City one</option>
          <option value="2">City two</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Textarea -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="message">Message</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">                     
        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: you question is not clear?

Comment: HTML5 added several new input types:

color,
date,
datetime-local,
email,
month,
number,
range,
search,
tel,
time,
url,
week

Comment: I need the user to have the Form filling by voice option